# How to do group using table component, not fields?

Tags: jasper-reports

The goal is to make something like that using groups

[image]

The problem is that I can construct it using fields, but when I export the report constructed from fields (like in most of tutorials) to Excel, it becomes a mess.
I want to use table component, maybe partly, just for the parts where row1, row2... etc are located, because tables are exported rather decently.
Is that possible at all?
If I add a table component into the details band, it shows the whole table for each group (all rows 1-9 are in each group, so I have no grouping at all), like here:

[image]

This is my XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8075ffe7-6e3e-430c-9792-0842e1047ee7">
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="6d70e59b-520c-4c3a-b122-fc299a1e36f3">
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select * from test_table]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="COLUMN1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="INITIATOR" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="URL" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DOMAIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from test_table]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="COLUMN1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="INITIATOR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="URL" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DOMAIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="USER">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{INITIATOR}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="20">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f3c7aeda-d5fc-4745-aa57-6b86527bca7d"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INITIATOR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="82" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="80" uuid="1e1e5c70-7231-407c-8a21-8a8abe18004c"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="c1fc144a-34ea-4a3c-bad5-979e248dbdd5">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="164" uuid="6fc1588c-ff53-457e-9ded-bf2ef1499ef9">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="164" height="30" uuid="37471666-30cf-4fba-a25a-2341517a9ff8"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[COLUMN1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="164" height="20" uuid="23a35d1a-1835-4f98-b948-2e20d170b7cb"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="143" uuid="3bb44350-b9a3-42f3-a4b4-24cc92c1ac7a">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="143" height="30" uuid="32882a4d-9af7-4d20-bffc-d97304f852ec"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[INITIATOR]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="143" height="20" uuid="624c6056-9c8d-469d-834e-052e7ba64205"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INITIATOR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="145" uuid="fdc25f77-cbf8-437b-9599-8dac13c231c7">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="145" height="30" uuid="9def11e0-f333-4af6-acd2-87693f546b94"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="145" height="20" uuid="bffecf39-515f-49fa-a2fd-dce3b899664a"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="215" uuid="ebcc9292-c0f8-45d7-acfb-a0cd07411c06">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="215" height="30" uuid="119558f5-9f63-408d-88fe-685bff93420c"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[URL]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="215" height="20" uuid="57fb4ae3-2ef8-46f5-9078-189afba2cc6f"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{URL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="134" uuid="f241a40c-8426-4b4f-ad01-fcda25e3891c">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="134" height="30" uuid="d3015f10-9258-4ac9-8e95-a00f450b751e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[DOMAIN]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="134" height="20" uuid="fab1275a-7ae9-443b-8861-fa7c319e01b1"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOMAIN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You can pass parameters to the table component and create you query so it fetches only data related the current item.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But I don't know how much groups I could have, so I have no idea, how to do that. Could you explain more extensively?

Comment: Please provide the jrxml you are using. I will have a look at it.

Comment: @AmitChotaliya I edited my post, please find my XML there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your jrxml. I passed id from the main query to the table component as parameter and used it in the query for where condition, so the table query will only return the rows which are related to the parent query id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="125"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1">
        <parameter name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select * from test_table where id = $P{id};]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="COLUMN1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="INITIATOR" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="URL" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DOMAIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from test_table;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="COLUMN1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="INITIATOR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="URL" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DOMAIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="USER">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{INITIATOR}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="20">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INITIATOR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="82" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="80"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1">
                        <datasetParameter name="id">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="164">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="164" height="30"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[COLUMN1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="164" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="143">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="143" height="30"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[INITIATOR]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="143" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INITIATOR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="145">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="145" height="30"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="145" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="215">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="215" height="30"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[URL]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="215" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{URL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="134">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="134" height="30"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[DOMAIN]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table 1_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="134" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOMAIN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't work for me, I got an exception in iReport, maybe you can explain how to do that in iReport?:  
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : report1      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:240)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1114)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: ???????? ??????

Comment: Please provide your db with data, don't put it here, put it in http://pastebin.com/ and paste the link.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand how to do what you ask. But finally I got how to make a decent template without table. Do you really just edit the XML, or you use iReport? if the latter, could you explain how to do it? Or direct editing the XML is the only way?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I just grouped fields without any tables, and I got quite decent XLS. I am not sure one needs to use tables for that problem. I am not sure why to use table component at all, frankly speaking. Anyway, thank you for the hint about parameters.

Comment: @Battle_Slug I am facing same issue. Do you got any solution? If yes then please share jrxml file. Thanks

Comment: @RupeshPatil That was too long time ago, and that was just proof of concept for some part of our project. Unfortunately I don't have that code anymore, sorry for that...